# Unity 3D - Moving an Object around a circle circumference facing forward

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I am using Unity3D to move the player around the circumference of a large circle facing inwards towards the centre at all times.

The following code works by using **transform.forward**

```
  // Rotate the forward vector towards the target direction
    Vector3 newDirection = Vector3.RotateTowards(transform.forward, targetDirection, singleStep, 0.0f);
```

and then I move the player sideways by using

```
characterController.Move(horizontalSpeed * transform.right * Time.deltaTime);
```

I have been stuck on how to get the player to move around the circumference but facing forward with the left of the player facing the centre of the circle.
My code is as follows

```
   void Start()
    {
        characterController = GetComponent<CharacterController>();

    }

    void Update()
    {


        // Determine which direction to rotate towards
        Vector3 targetDirection = GameObject.Find("Platforms").transform.position - transform.position;

        // The step size is equal to speed times frame time.
        float singleStep = 1 * Time.deltaTime;

        // Rotate the forward vector towards the target direction by one step
        Vector3 newDirection = Vector3.RotateTowards(transform.forward, targetDirection, singleStep, 0.0f);

        // Draw a ray pointing at our target in
        Debug.DrawRay(transform.position, newDirection*50, Color.red);

        // Calculate a rotation a step closer to the target and applies rotation to this object
        transform.rotation = Quaternion.LookRotation(newDirection);

        CheckIfOnGround();

        characterController.Move(velocity * Time.deltaTime);

    }
```

Comment: so currently you are calculating the players rotation with him looking towards the center, but now you want a 90° angle to the center? You could use `transform.right` instead of `transform.forward`

Comment: If I change it to Transform.Right or - TransformRight it just spins around

Comment: please use the correct tags ... [`unityscript`](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/unityscript/info) is or better **was** a JavaScript flavor like custom language used in early Unity versions and is long deprecated by now ... your code is clearly `c#`

Answer (score 0):

Replace `transform.forward` to `transform.left`

Comment: If I add Transform.Right or - TransformRight it just spins around

Comment: Hello and welcome to SO! Please read the [tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour), and [How do I write a good answer?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer) Try to elaborate what are the differences, and how it solves theproblem.

Comment: Vector3 newDirection = Vector3.RotateTowards(transform.right, targetDirection, singleStep, 0.0f);